# spotlight search results are all false and reseted through terminal, but spotlight still continues to absorb all cpu space? (Macos big sur 11.2.3)

Tags: macos, cpu, spotlight, macos-bigsur

I've tried many solutions, but all of them doesn't seem to work, ever since i did a `ng generate component my-component` an angular command for generating documents. after that command my laptops fans suddenly started firing, I'm assuming this is a problem with the new macos, on the previous one i just restarted and that seemed to work. So here is what i tried:

First My privacy only has my userdocument named my name, which i added

[my search results list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ImsO.png)

For now i turned off spotlight with this command

```
sudo mdutil -i off /
```

According to a thread called "mds and mds_stores constantly consuming cpu
" after turning it off you do two commands to reset it

```
sudo mdutil -a -i on
sudo rm -rf /.Spotlight-V100/*
```

After doing that i expected no cpu usage since all my search results are false, but it just sky rocketed again, after that i did first aid on HD and nothing seems to be wrong.

[activity monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RapQs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I was writing this question, i came up with an answer to my own question and thought maybe people will find this somewhat helpful, so funny enough all i had to do is wait a few minutes and then the cpu usage went down, and this is with all search results false, after that you could customise what you want to see, or maybe even select all search results again.

You'll have to turn off spotlight and turn it back on using the commands mentioned in the question to apply search results from the spotlight preferences window and also change privacy to contain nothing.